# Atmega328p FT232RL invalid device identifier

Tags: atmega328p, avrdude

I have this little guy
[image: Little dude I got from my father]

and I want to read it's code, edit it and rewrite
[image: inside the little dude]

This guy fortunately ready and as far as I found out equipped with

Atmega328p
[image: Atmega328p]

and FT232RL
[image: FT232RL]

I have: Centos 8, Arduino IDE, avrdude 6.3-20171130 (compiled today)

I did
`avrdude -p m328p -P ft0 -c uncompatino -vvv -U flash:w:flash.hex` with different -c (ft232r, arduino-ft232r, diecimila, uncompatino) and -P (ft0, ttyUSB0) all gave the same result

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/opt/avrdude/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : ft0
         Using Programmer              : uncompatino
avrdude: <unknown>: Pin is ok.
avrdude: VCC: Pin is ok.
avrdude: BUFF: Pin is ok.
avrdude: RESET: Pin is ok.
avrdude: SCK: Pin is ok.
avrdude: MOSI: Pin is ok.
avrdude: MISO: Pin is ok.
avrdude: ERRLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: RDYLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: PGMLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: VFYLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: ft245r_open(): invalid device identifier '        '

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Also tried to add some stuff to my avrdude.conf that I got from the internet

```
programmer
  id    = "APU-2";
  desc  = "FT232RL with 74hc125";
  type  = "ftdi_syncbb";
  connection_type = usb;
  miso  = 4;  # выв. 2 ft232rl
  sck   = 2;  # выв. 3 ft232rl
  mosi  = 6;  # выв. 10 ft232rl
  reset = 5;  # выв. 9 ft232rl
  buff  = ~3; # выв. 11 ft232rl
;
```

`$ dmesg | tail`

```
[ 2909.002278] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6750.283200] usb 1-13: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 6750.415079] usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 6750.415080] usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6750.415080] usb 1-13: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 6750.415081] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 6750.415081] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: ********
[ 6750.418234] ftdi_sio 1-13:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 6750.418253] usb 1-13: Detected FT232RL
[ 6750.418479] usb 1-13: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

**EDIT 1:**
Fixed `-P` to `usb:<SerialNumber>` or `usb:ft0` and now I get this:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/opt/avrdude/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb:ft0
         Using Programmer              : ft232r
avrdude: <unknown>: Pin is ok.
avrdude: VCC: Pin is ok.
avrdude: BUFF: Pin is ok.
avrdude: RESET: Pin is ok.
avrdude: SCK: Pin is ok.
avrdude: MOSI: Pin is ok.
avrdude: MISO: Pin is ok.
avrdude: ERRLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: RDYLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: PGMLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: VFYLED: Pin is ok.
avrdude: ft245r_open(): device number parsed as: 0
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : ftdi_syncbb
         Description     : FT232R Synchronous BitBang
         Pin assignment  : 0..7 = DBUS0..7
           VCC     =  (not used)
           BUFF    =  (not used)
           RESET   =  4
           SCK     =  0
           MOSI    =  2
           MISO    =  1
           ERR LED =  (not used)
           RDY LED =  (not used)
           PGM LED =  (not used)
           VFY LED =  (not used)

avrdude: Device is not responding to program enable. Check connection.
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You *do* realise that you're not going to extract the original source code, don't you?

Comment: @Transistor, source or not, I just want to make this thing work.

Comment: That's the point. As far as I know the most you can hope for is the compiled machine code which, judging by the photos, is going to be very far from trivial. What are you hoping to fix when you have the compiled code?

Comment: Is there any chance to get that compiled machine code? I can see check running when I turn it on. It has objects sensor connected to it, two motors and two reflective optical sensors. Would be great to make this thing move, detect objects, but now I just want to pass `avrdude` initialization when I try to connect.

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting my point. The code you'll get, if successful, will be just a load of hex bytes. No 'C' code. No comments. (1) What do you hope to do with this hex code? (2) Any problems you have are most likely hardware related. Why are you looking into the code?